# Table insert gives a nil error

Tags: lua, lua-table

I have the following function in my lua code. I am getting an error `Attempt to call field 'insert' (a nil value)`

I have above in main chunck

```
local cardDeck;
local suits = {"h","d","c","s"};
```

then in function

```
function createDeck()
    cardDeck = {};
    for i=1, 4 do
        for j=1, 13 do
            local tempCard = suits[i]..j;--PRINT SHOW VALID VALUE HERE i.e. "h1","d2" etc
                table.insert(cardDeck,tempCard); --THIS LINE IS ERROR
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Can you post the minimal complete code chunk that reproduces this error? The posted code as shown doesn't produce that error in question. (ignoring the misscomment on `table.insert`)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you sure you haven't defined `table` elsewhere in your program?

```
> table.insert({},1)
> table = {}
> table.insert({},1)
stdin:1: attempt to call field 'insert' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
    stdin:1: in main chunk
    [C]: ?
```

Comment: glad I could help, this happens to the best of us haha :)